# Working on a trigonometry quiz website with HTML, CSS, Javascript, and I want to show % correct on the quiz but nothing displays

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a JS method calculateScore() which is called when the user submits an answer so every time an answer is submitted, the score % is recalculated. However it stays at 0%. I'm displaying it with a paragraph tag set to 0% in HTML and then the JS used getElementById and innerHTML to set the `<p>` equal to the correct % however nothing is updated. If I try to call the method I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null. If I set the div containing the `<p>` to have an onload that calls the method no information is updated. Does this mean I have to move the `<p>` above the submit button so that it isn't null when called? Sorry if the formatting is bad I'm new here.

Comment: Hey, post the code please so we have a [mcve]. All we can do is guess without your code. That said, sounds like whatever you're setting `innerHTML` of isn't valid, so you might make sure you're targeting the correct element.

Comment: Sorry! Wasn't sure if I would annoy people by posting tons of code. How should I format a couple hundred lines of code for this site? Just paste it in?

Comment: just user jsfiddleor codepen.io to put your code and try to remove the unnecessary code for your question if possible

Comment: <script async src="//jsfiddle.net/keuy19ed/1/embed/"></script>

Comment: Hope I did that correctly!

Comment: Heres the colab link: https://jsfiddle.net/keuy19ed/3/#&togetherjs=T5z2aOVICd

Comment: Ah I left that out because it said to leave out stuff not contributing to the problem.

Comment: You should read the link I posted. We need the code **in the post itself** - not a link to a third party site like jsfiddle. Jsfiddle is fine, but you need to include your code here, too. And you don't need to post hundreds of line of code. A **minimal**, complete, verifiable example should include the minimal amount of code needed to illustrate/reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used dash "-" in your html id and low dash "_" in your JavaScript so you can't get the right element :

```
<li id="percentage-correct">Percentage: 0%</li>
```

---

```
document.getElementById("percentage_correct").innerHTML = "Percentage: " + Math.floor((numCorrect / numIncorrect) * 100) + "%";
```

Also if you want to calculate the percentage of success I think your calcul is incorrect : I will replace numIncorrect by numQuestions

Comment: Wow I can't believe I spent so much time trying to figure that out when it was just an underscore instead of a dash. And yes you are correct I did do the wrong calculations. Thank you so much!

Comment: I think I marked your response as the correct answer let me know if I messed up though!

Comment: Good :) happy to help and you did good as marking the correct answer.